# How to dump sqlite database to ascii?

Tags: linux, sqlite

For some reason Firefox won't let me see more than 1 month of history, despite I have set to to remember for 90 days.

`places.sqlite` is 18MB so I would like to dump the content of it, and see if I can find the missing history.

Does anyone know how to dump/export to a flat ascii file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a flat ASCII file, you may also find using a tool such as [SQLite Manager](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/) useful to browse or edit your SQLite file. (It can run either as a Firefox add-on or as a standalone XUL application.)

Answer (score 7):

Just figured it out.

```
sqlite3 places.sqlite .dump |grep moz_places
```